# Formula to repeat a previous row multiple times based on a number in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, unique, repeat

I have multiple lines of data that refer to x number of females and x number of males per line.

I need to break them out into individual records (1 row for each). Is there an excel formula that would look at the first row and based on the number in column D, return that number of rows and the data in a, b, c is same, however, for columns e, f, g, h, replace that many records with a 1 all in another sheet?

See screen image. There are 9 rows with a 1 in level 1, 17 with a 1 in level 2, etc. I have tried basic formulas combos that work but are time-consuming and there are 1342 rows that need to be broken into individual records.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL0L1.png)

Here is the sheet after the unpivot you suggested David. [Table after unpivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIBkX.png)

[codeandoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD4CV.png)

CODE FOR 5 LEVELS with code for slow issues
Sub CreateIndividualRecordsLevel5()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim e As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim instancesInRow As Long
    Dim level1 As Long
    Dim level2 As Long
    Dim level3 As Long
    Dim level4 As Long
    Dim level5 As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("WHITE")

n = 0


' Outer loop 'goes' through your original table and for each cell in
' column D checks how many instances there are.
For i = 2 To 523

        instancesInRow = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        level1 = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
        level2 = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
        level3 = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
        level4 = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
        level5 = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value

        ' Inner loop 'knows' how many times it needs to loop-copy the same
        ' row into the new table/worksheet.
        For a = 1 To level1
                n = n + 1
                ws.Range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Value
                ws.Range("N" & n).Value = 1
                ws.Range("O" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("P" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("Q" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("R" & n).Value = 0
        Next a

        For b = 1 To level2
                n = n + 1
                ws.Range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Value
                ws.Range("N" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("O" & n).Value = 1
                ws.Range("P" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("Q" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("R" & n).Value = 0
        Next b

        For c = 1 To level3
                n = n + 1
                ws.Range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Value
                ws.Range("N" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("O" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("P" & n).Value = 1
                ws.Range("Q" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("R" & n).Value = 0
        Next c

        For d = 1 To level4
                n = n + 1
                ws.Range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Value
                ws.Range("N" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("O" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("P" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("Q" & n).Value = 1
                ws.Range("R" & n).Value = 0
        Next d

        For e = 1 To level5
                n = n + 1
                ws.Range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":I" & i).Value
                ws.Range("N" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("O" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("P" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("Q" & n).Value = 0
                ws.Range("R" & n).Value = 1

        Next e


                ' Counter n counts how many rows you have copied so far,
                'in order to know in which row to copy to the new range

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure why you ask for a formula if it can return multiple rows, as to my best knowledge a formula affects only that cell's value that it is entered into. What you need is an unpivot functionality I believe, try to search for that for your Excel version.

Comment: Your suggestion was perfect!. THank you. However, I need to analyze the data, but because it is x number of females or x number of males per row, SPSS will count the rows, and the data does not come in "individual student level." I performed an unpivot in excel and it broke the data down by  levels in one column and the number of females or males in the next column, but I need those to be individual lines, I need 9 rows of level 1 county female PENF and I tried to do another unpivot from the new sheet and it doesn't break out the 9 into individual rows. Any other suggestions David?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I made a mistake and it took a bit longer. Here we go:

Check the image with the result here >>> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IILsq.png)

```
    Private Sub testcopyrow()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim e As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim instancesInRow As Long
    Dim level1 As Long
    Dim level2 As Long
    Dim level3 As Long
    Dim level4 As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SplitRowsByInstances")

    n = 0

    ' Outer loop 'goes' through your original table and for each cell in
    ' column D checks how many instances there are.
    For i = 2 To 7

            instancesInRow = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
            level1 = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
            level2 = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
            level3 = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
            level4 = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value

            ' Inner loop 'knows' how many times it needs to loop-copy the same
            ' row into the new table/worksheet.
            For a = 1 To level1
                    n = n + 1
                    ws.range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                    ws.range("N" & n).Value = 1
                    ws.range("O" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("P" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("Q" & n).Value = 0
            Next a

            For b = 1 To level2
                    n = n + 1
                    ws.range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                    ws.range("N" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("O" & n).Value = 1
                    ws.range("P" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("Q" & n).Value = 0
            Next b

            For c = 1 To level3
                    n = n + 1
                    ws.range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                    ws.range("N" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("O" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("P" & n).Value = 1
                    ws.range("Q" & n).Value = 0
            Next c

            For d = 1 To level4
                    n = n + 1
                    ws.range("J" & n & ":M" & n).Value = ws.range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value
                    ws.range("N" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("O" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("P" & n).Value = 0
                    ws.range("Q" & n).Value = 1
            Next d


                    ' Counter n counts how many rows you have copied so far,
                    'in order to know in which row to copy to the new range

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Let me know if I helped!

Comment: See pic in original titled Cod and output. I don't think I am on the same path as you. UGH!!

Comment: I should clarify, I want the output, and now Im lost.

Comment: Never mind. I was so focused on code that I forgot that a simple column added with first cell starting at 01 all the way to the end 192000 and a simple concatenate formula did the trick. OMG11

Comment: Hi Amateur, I have a file with five levels and adjusted the code to include the 5th level column, and everything is working EXCEPT, it is not continuing to add the data. My laptop won't let it do more than a few hundred rows so when I start with the next set of 200, it overwrites the last output. I have looked at the entire code and cannot see where my mistake is. I added the new code above in orginial post.

Comment: Hello, the code looks good. I think it should work the same way as before. What do you mean by it's not continuing to add data. It stops at some point? Is there an error? Try to figure out exactly where it stops and take a look at the code again

Comment: Must be the worksheet, is everything in the place that it should be so that the code can get the proper input?

Comment: When I run the code for rows 2-7 all the records show up starting in J1. I My laptop crashes if I try more than 100-200 records so I do 2 To 100 and next I do 101 To 200 and the records for the next set of rows starts in J1, overwriting the data from 2 To 100. It did not do this last night.

Comment: It is as though there is a code somewhere that says use J1 as output starting place. It went to the next empty cell yesterday below the last row of data that generated and continued every time I ran the macro, changing the starting and ending row each time. Today, it just overwrites everytime so I cut and paste and then run the macro till I have done every row.

Comment: Oh, that is because the "n" counter lets the macro know which row it 'filled' last. When you run the macro again, it starts from 1.
It's designed to be run for the entire set at once.

Comment: If you want to run 1 to 10, then 11 to 20 etc. you would have to change the first declaration of 'n' in the macro - each time. And this is quite problematic, you would have to manually check which row it was, and edit it in the macro.
Now with this many repetitions there is a big chance you make a mistake and you will lose data without even knowing it!

Comment: Say you run first time from 1 to 5 with the 'n' counter set to 0 as default by me. If you want to run again from 6 to 11, you need to set 'n = 5'. Then if you want to run it again, you would need to set 'n = 11' etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I can't run more without it crashing. I have a new laptop with 8 GB ram, and a 2.4 i5 and normally it does fine, but this code crashes my Excel. Even that screen refresh line from the other site doesn't help

Comment: Add these two lines in the same place where the screen refresh:
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False Application.EnableEvents = False

And in the end of code set them to 'True'.

I tried running such a file on my laptop - also a new one, also with i5, however I've got 16GB RAM and a very fast Samsung SSD nvme, it does not crash for 5,000 lines. Just how many records do you have?

Comment: keep or replace screen refresh?

Comment: Each workbook file has 500 to 1500 lines but the output will be well over 100,000. I added the lines and kept the others and it has not crashed, but still working after 10 mins.

Comment: Keep them all, these all turn of unnecessary features that slow down the code

Comment: With an output of 100,000 you have to take into the account that it may take a lot of time. Keep the excel window small, so that you can see the top of the VBA Editor window, and in the title of the VBA editor window it's written "RUNNING", and you will have to wait quite a lot I guess.

Comment: It won't run at all. Not sure. Its the same code for 5 levels I posted above with the new code to keep it from slowing. I updated the code above.

Comment: I took out the code for slowing and dropped it down to 50 rows. Its slow but working. Last night I did 1334 rows in a few minutes. Not sure whats up today.

Comment: At the top of the code you just posted change 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic' into 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual'. Else your worksheet is recalculating all the changes while the macro is runnig!

Comment: That was it. Ran 500 rows and 50000 output in less than 30 seconds. THANK YOU! THANKYOU!